# ggstance::geom_barh not flipping axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Posting [this](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance/issues/18) for a more general audience

Consider the following:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg, ggplot2::aes(class)) + ggplot2::geom_bar()
```

This yields
[image: rplot]

However

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg, ggplot2::aes(class)) + ggstance::geom_barh()
```

produces the (broken!?)
[image: rplot01]
Where am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `stat`:

```
stat_counth <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                       geom = "fillbar", position = "stack",
                       ...,
                       width = NULL,
                       na.rm = FALSE,
                       show.legend = NA,
                       inherit.aes = TRUE) {

  params <- list(
    na.rm = na.rm,
    width = width,
    ...
  )
  if (!is.null(params$y)) {
    stop("stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.", call. = FALSE)
  }

  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = StatCounth,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = params
  )
}

#' @rdname ggplot2-ggproto
#' @format NULL
#' @usage NULL
#' @export
#' @include stat-.r
StatCounth <- ggproto("StatCounth", Stat,
  required_aes = "y",
  default_aes = aes(x = calc(count), weight = 1),

  setup_params = function(data, params) {
   if (!is.null(data$y)) {
     stop("stat_counth() must not be used with a x aesthetic.", call. = FALSE)
   }
   params
  },

  compute_group = function(self, data, scales, width = NULL) {
   y <- data$y
   weight <- data$weight %||% rep(1, length(y))
   width <- width %||% (resolution(y) * 0.9)

   count <- as.numeric(tapply(weight, y, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
   count[is.na(count)] <- 0

   data.frame(
     count = count,
     prop = count / sum(abs(count)),
     x = sort(unique(y)),
     width = width
   )
  }
)
```

Then plot as follows:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg, ggplot2::aes(y = class)) + ggstance::geom_barh(stat = "counth")
```

[image]

Edit: Actually this stat is also implemented in `ggstance`, seems to just have been forgotten to make it default.

This works too:

`ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg, ggplot2::aes(y = class)) + ggstance::geom_barh(stat = ggstance::StatCounth)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to flip the axes you can use the following:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

Comment: I agree, however as the `ggstance` github site points out: "While coord_flip() can only flip a plot as a whole, ggstance provides flipped versions of Geoms, Stats and Positions. This makes it easier to build horizontal layer or use vertical positioning (e.g. vertical dodging). Also, horizontal Geoms draw horizontal legend keys to keep the appearance of your plots consistent."

So I would love to use `geom_barh` ...

Comment: Ah I see.  I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with `ggstance::geom_barh`.

Remember, with `ggstance`, you must supply aesthetics in their natural order. `geom_barh` will flip the geom *only*; it will not flip the axes like `coord_flip()`. For your example to work, you would have to do this:

```
ggplot(mpg, (aes(y = class) +
  geom_barh()
```

However, this produces an error:

`Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`